# Google Identity Toolkit federated login and OAuth access tokens

Tags: oauth, google-api, access-token

I have successfully implemented user authentication using GITKit and I was wondering if it's possible to get OAuth access tokens to be able to access user's gmail account, address book etc...

Could you guys, help me to figure it out ? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, [verifyAssertion](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/v1/reference/relyingparty/verifyAssertion) has parameter **returnOauthToken** which will add oauth token to the data returned by it.